# adding fixable errors using phpcs

Tags: php, phpcs

When I call addFixableError in phpcs the output shows a fixable error as expected,
however in the sniff code I check the return and this is false and I would therefore expect the output from phpcs to show that the error is not fixable.

I am correct in this assumptino or am I missing something?

It seems that phpcs_file->fixer->enabled is false

how do i correctly set this value?

sniff code -

```
        $phpcs_file->fixer->beginChangeset();
    $fix = $phpcs_file->addFixableError ($error, $stack_ptr, 'FunctionNameInvalid', $data);
    if ($fix === true) {
        $token = $tokens[$stack_ptr +2];
        $token['content'] = $snake_case_string;
        if ($phpcs_file->fixer->replaceToken ($stack_ptr, "asasd") === false) {
            print("could not replace\n");
        }
    } else {
        print("could not fix\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time PHPCS will ask a sniff to fix errors is when it is printing a `diff` report. At all other times, PHPCS only shows errors and doesn't fix them.

The companion script, PHPCBF, is the one that does the fixing by overwriting files with a fixed copy.

If you want to auto-fix a file, use PHPCBF. If you just want to see what the fixes would look like, use PHPCS with the diff report. In both cases, the return value of `addFixableError` will be `true`. In all other cases, the return value will be `false`.

So those two commands to get a `true` return value would be:

`phpcbf /path/to/file.php`

or

`phpcs /path/to/file.php --report=diff`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - it really helped<br/> The root of my confusion came from the fact that when phpcs creates a diff it uses the ob_start command so I was not seeing any of my outpu